# Loading google maps api with libraries

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to load both the main api and a library (Places) into my web application.  According to the documentation, I'm supposed to load the Places library with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

But when I use this in combination with my script tag to load the main api, it gives me an error that I'm loading the api twice.  How could I load both in the same script tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've specified the `places` in the `libraries` param, you only need that one script. According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries):

```
The JavaScript code for the Maps API is loaded via a bootstrap URL of the 
form http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js.
This bootstrap request loads all of the main Javascript objects and symbols 
for use in the Maps API. Some Maps API features are also available in 
self-contained libraries which are not loaded unless you specifically 
request them.
```

Comment: okay thanks!  i tried it with just that and i still get a bunch of errors but theyre all my own code :(

Comment: @ChristTherapist Glad to be of service! If you found the answer helpful, don't forget to mark it correct ;)

Comment: im trying!  it tells me i have to wait a couple more minutes.  don't worry though, you'll be marked correct ASAP :D